# Add loop to bullet formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word, editing

I started with a basic macro to find any bullets in my document and added to it by recording a macro that would apply our company bullet style. However, I have trouble inserting a loop and keep getting an error message.

Is there a simple way to clean this up and have it run through the whole document?

```
Sub FindAndReplacewithCompanyBullet()

 Application.Run MacroName:="FindBullet"
 Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Company Bullet List")
 With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.38)
 End With
 With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.44)
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
 End With
 With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.31)
 End With
 With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.31)
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
 End With
  With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.18)
 End With
Next Para
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats that `Nest Para`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
Dim values(3,2) As Single, I as Integer
values(1,1) = -0.38
values(1,2) = 0.44
values(2,1) = -0.31
values(2,2) = 0.44
values(3,1) = -0.18
values(3,2) = 0

For i = 1 To 3
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(values(i,1))
        If values(i,2) <> 0 Then
            .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(values(i,2))
        End If
     End With
Next i
```

Comment: I keep getting "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" for the line that says ".FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints (values(2, I))". How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: @CatherineCombs It was my fault, check the new code ;).